# English translation for the party motto: "Oben hui, unten Pfui"

Tags: translation

In Germany, there's a party motto called "Oben hui, unten Pfui".

Is there an English version of this motto? If not, could be a proper translation?

Comment: This question is appropriate on our sister site ELU.

Comment: @Em1 did not know this page. Is it possible to transfer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't think of a direct translation, there is the opportunity of making a play on an existing idiomatic phrase in American English:

In regards to the infamous *Mullet* hairstyle, people often say "Business in the front, party in the back", referring to the haircut's business-appropriate look from the front, but garish and unprofessional style in the back of the head.

Playing off this known phrase, you could say **"Business up top, party down below."**

Answer (score 0):

"Hui" means like "wow" = very elegant
"Pfui" means "bah, disgusting!" = indelicate / inappropriate